# Faster way to attach 2d polynomial coefficients to terms in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials

So I am trying to create a polynomial that contains 2 independent variables by attaching the respective coefficients (`k_ij`) to the respective monomial (`x**i*y**j`, where `x` and `y` are symbolic variables).  My goal is to *minimize computation time* because my polynomial is very large, and the main thing using computation time in my program is the set of lines that generate this symbolic polynomial (and I will need to call this step multiple times).  I was very surprised to realize how much time this step took in the program, considering that the rest of my program was rather lengthy/complex. I would never have guessed how much time it takes to simply create the monomials and attach the coefficients to create a polynomial.

My polynomial does not necessarily have to be saved as a polynomial, it just has to be a sum of all of the terms. By this, I mean I do not need an output like this...

```
Out: Poly(7*x + 2*y, x, y, domain='ZZ')
```

... although, I am not against that format, either, if it minimizes computation time.  What I would like, but do not necessarily need, is simply an output that looks something like this (which, in said case, can be achieved by simply saying `z = 7*x + 2*y` if `x` and `y` are already defined symbolically):

```
Out: 7*x + 2*y
```

So, I have a coefficient matrix (which can easily be re-ordered to fit the method used to attach it to the polynomial) that contains all of the coefficients of the desired polynomial, and I have my symbolic variables.  Here is a re-creation of my first attempt (which took the most time to compute):

```
import sympy
import time
# let's time it, see how long it takes
from time import clock as tc

# time it!
t0 = tc()

order = 33
order_x = order
order_y = order
deg_x = order - 1
deg_y = order - 1

nnn = order_x*order_y

# here is a random coefficient matrix
coefficient_matrix = numpy.random.rand(nnn)

# define symbolic variables
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')

# now let's populate the surface polynomial
z = 0
for i2 in range(order_y):
    for i3 in range(order_x):
        z = z + coefficient_matrix[i3 + order_x*i2]*(x**(deg_x - i3))*(y**(deg_y - i2))
        # note that this returns high order to low order terms

t1 = tc()
print(t1-t0)
```

That was very slow (37s), presumably because of the nature of the `for` loop. I then tried using `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d` to generate a pseudo-vandermonde matrix and multiplying it to the coefficient matrix, but that made almost no difference in computation time.  The next method I tried, shown below, was able to put a big dent in computation time:

```
import sympy
import time
from time import clock as tc
import numpy
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval2d as P2

# time it!
t0 = tc()

order = 33
order_x = order
order_y = order

# here is a random coefficient matrix
coefficient_matrix = numpy.random.rand(order, order)

# define symbolic variables
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')

# create polynomial
z = P2(x, y, coefficient_matrix)

# make the polynomial a logical sequence of monomials
z = sympy.expand(z)

t1 = tc()
print(z)
print(t1-t0)
```

This method took 8.5 seconds (which really surprised me, I thought it would be much shorter), but without the `z = sympy.expand(z)` line it took about 3 seconds.  The reason I have that line is that later I need to modify the function and extract the new coefficients, so I would like it in that expanded form for later use (so that it appears in the format listed above; if I did not include this line, it appears in sort of a factored format).

Is there a way to make Python match the terms with the coefficients even faster and return them as a sequence of monomials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Constructing a `sy.Poly`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/polynomials.html#poly) would take a lot less time:

```
using_loop          : 43.56
using_P2            : 12.64
using_poly          :  0.03
```

---

```
from timeit import default_timer as tc
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval2d as P2


def using_poly(coefficient_matrix, S=sy.S):
    order = coefficient_matrix.shape[0]
    x = sy.Symbol('x')
    y = sy.Symbol('y')
    dct = {i:S(val) for i, val in np.ndenumerate(coefficient_matrix)}
    z = sy.Poly(dct, x, y)
    return z

def using_loop(coefficient_matrix):
    order = coefficient_matrix.shape[0]
    coefficient_matrix = coefficient_matrix.T.ravel()[::-1]
    order_x = order
    order_y = order
    deg_x = order - 1
    deg_y = order - 1
    x = sy.Symbol('x')
    y = sy.Symbol('y')
    z = 0
    for i2 in range(order_y):
        for i3 in range(order_x):
            z = z + coefficient_matrix[i3 + order_x*i2]*(x**(deg_x - i3))*(y**(deg_y - i2))
    return z

def using_P2(coefficient_matrix):
    x = sy.Symbol('x')
    y = sy.Symbol('y')
    z = P2(x, y, coefficient_matrix)
    # make the polynomial a logical sequence of monomials
    z = sy.expand(z)
    return z

order = 33
np.random.seed(2015)
coefficient_matrix = np.random.rand(order, order)
# coefficient_matrix = np.arange(1, order*order+1).reshape(order,order)

for func in (using_loop, using_P2, using_poly):
    t0 = tc()
    func(coefficient_matrix)
    t1 = tc()
    print('{:15s}: {:>5.2f}'.format(func.__name__, t1-t0))
```

---

Here is an example of what the output looks like for a small coefficient_matrix:

```
In [277]: order = 3

In [278]: coefficient_matrix = np.arange(1, order*order+1).reshape(order,order)

In [279]: using_poly(coefficient_matrix)
Out[279]: Poly(9*x**2*y**2 + 8*x**2*y + 7*x**2 + 6*x*y**2 + 5*x*y + 4*x + 3*y**2 + 2*y + 1, x, y, domain='ZZ')

In [280]: using_P2(coefficient_matrix)
Out[280]: 9.0*x**2*y**2 + 8.0*x**2*y + 7.0*x**2 + 6.0*x*y**2 + 5.0*x*y + 4.0*x + 3.0*y**2 + 2.0*y + 1.0

In [281]: using_loop(coefficient_matrix)
Out[281]: 9*x**2*y**2 + 8*x**2*y + 7*x**2 + 6*x*y**2 + 5*x*y + 4*x + 3*y**2 + 2*y + 1
```